# How to handle a left click on a control's scrollbar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a control (a text editor control) that uses the default scrollbar to scroll the text. However, clicking the scrollbar only makes it scroll a few lines.

I want to handle the scrollbar left click on my own, and make it scroll page down / page up, depending on the click, if it's above the scrollbar thumb, then page up, if it's below the thumb, page down.

TL;DR I want to know how to handle a left click on a default scrollbar and whether the cursor is above/below the scrollbar thumb. I know there's the `Scroll` event but it occurs after the user has scrolled, I want something like `Scrolling`.

Answer (score 2):

If by "default scrollbar" you mean the scrollbars that are part of any `ScrollableControl` (UserControl, etc.), there's no need to handle the click event. The [`VScrollProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.vscrollproperties) class already gives you control over this out of the box:

- Use `ScrollableControl.VerticalScroll.SmallChange` to set the distance the scroll should move when the user clicks on the scrollbar *buttons (arrows)*.
- Use `ScrollableControl.VerticalScroll.LargeChange` to set the distance the scroll should move when the user clicks on an *empty space* on the scrollbar.

**Demo:**

[image: VScroll properties demo]